# Rubymine Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rubymine

I'm using RubyMine and following the guide on their website here [Rubymine in 7minutes](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/demos/rubymine_7_minutes.html) And after creating my basic scaffold, and running db:migrate I go to launch the server, the localhost main page works, i.e. when you first create a RoR app. However, when I attempt to navigate to http://localhost:3000/ideas it complains of a routing error, saying:

> No route matches "/ideas"

My `routes.rb` looks like this:

```
AntrageUno::Application.routes.draw do
  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.

  # Sample of regular route:
  #   match 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
  # Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

  # Sample of named route:
  #   match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', :as => :purchase
  # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

  # Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Sample resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', :on => :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
  # root :to => "welcome#index"

  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

  # This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
  # Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
  # match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
end
```

I'm new to RoR so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I updated the question to include what it looks like, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `resources :ideas` in your routes.rb file